# String count - identify key words and dismissing compound words

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have created a program for an assignment which reads a txt file and returns key words. My program returns the key words but there s one issue with one of the words 'data'. I should only get 6 results for this but I am getting 7. The reason, i assume, is there is a compound word present in the text 'data - analytics'. The program seems to be picking this up and counting it in the final result. Is there anything I could insert into the end of my code to dismiss this?

```
import string
text = open('news1.txt').read()+open ('news2.txt').read()
print 'data:', string.count(text, 'data')
```

Comment: Just include a space before and after?

Comment: Have you tried printing what's in `text`, or saving it to a file, and looking for instance of `data` manually? One obvious problem, which I think is what @sdasdadas was alluding to, is that if `news1.txt` ends with "dat" and `news2.txt` starts with "a", that'll show up as an instance of `"data"` if you just add them together.

Comment: As a side note, why are you using [`string.count`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#deprecated-string-functions)? The documentation explicitly says that this function has been deprecated since Python 2.0, and you should use the `str` method instead. (That is, `txt.count('data')`.) This isn't going to cause a problem like what you're seeing, but it's still a bad idea.

Comment: Anyway, if you want us to debug your code, you'll have to give us input files that reproduce the problem. Ideally stripped-down files, as short as possible while still causing the same bug, but if you can't think of how to do that, just post the original files you're using.

Comment: One more side note: You shouldn't leak files like this. In this case, it won't hurt you, because the OS will force the files closed as soon as your script ends a few milliseconds later, and since you've only opened files read-only you don't care if they get flushed. But it's a bad habit to get into. Either explicitly `close` them, or use a `with` statement.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to be sure without seeing your actual input files, but there's one obvious possibility:

news1.txt:

```
data data data dat
```

news2.txt

```
a data data data
```

There are only 6 instances of the word "data" in the files. But if you concatenate the files, you get this:

```
data data data data data data data
```

… and you will count 7 instead of 6.

And it's perfectly plausible that your teacher gave you files that look like that in order to catch exactly this kind of bug. Edge cases that don't come up very often in the wild, and that you didn't think to test for, are exactly the kinds of things that cost you months of frustration—trying to drag repro information out of users, debugging the program, etc. It's a good lesson to learn early on in your programming life.